# JavaFX ComboBox shows scrollbars on first click

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, fxml

I'm doing a program in JavaFX with ComboBoxes, and loading a FXML for the layout.

When I click for the first time in a ComboBox with few items (only two, for example), the scrollbar is shown at the right side. After I open it again, the scrollbar doesn't appear anymore.

I tried some solutions. One that worked is to apply a CSS directly in the FXML, which sets the cell size to a fixed value. But a solution inside the code (for example, in the initialize function in the controller) would be better for my case.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be fixed in recent JDK versions, see  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095019

Answer (score 0):

If the options would stay fixed I would suggest using `ChoiceBox` instead of `ComboBox`. It is basically the same, but without the scrollable option. If you insist using `ComboBox` you can try `combobox.setVisibleRowCount()`